# AttributeError: 'SimpleTable' object has no attribute 'column'

Tags: python, regression, data-analysis

I am trying to export the summary of my multiple regression models in a table.

```
results = {'A':result.summary(), 
           'B': result1.summary(), 'C': result2.summary(), 'D': result3.summary(), 'E' : result4.summary()}
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Model':[], 'Param':[], 'Value':[]})
for mod in results.keys():
    for col in results[mod].tables[0].columns:
        if col % 2 == 0: 
            df2 = df2.append(pd.DataFrame({'Model': [mod]*results[mod].tables[0][col].size,
                                         'Param':results[mod].tables[0][col].values, 
                                         'Value':results[mod].tables[0][col+1].values}))

print(df2)
```

When I run the code it gives me error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-280-952fff354224> in <module>
      3 df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Model':[], 'Param':[], 'Value':[]})
      4 for mod in results.keys():
----> 5     for col in results[mod].tables[0].column:
      6         if col % 2 == 0:
      7             df2 = df2.append(pd.DataFrame({'Model': [mod]*results[mod].tables[0][col].size,

AttributeError: 'SimpleTable' object has no attribute 'column'
```

Comment: The error says that _'SimpleTable' object has no attribute 'column'_ and it says that for line with `results[mod].tables[0].column`. Therefore `results[mod].tables[0]` is a `SimpleTable` object and `SimpleTable` has no attribute `column`. Which part of that is not clear? What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

The SimpleTable in this context is [statsmodels.iolib.table.SimpleTable](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.iolib.table.SimpleTable.html). We can use pandas.DataFrame.from_records to convert the data type to DataFrame. From here, you can access the columns easily.

Assure this SimpleTable is accessed through a variable named "t"

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(t.data)
header = df.iloc[0] # grab the first row for the header
df = df[1:] # take the data less the header row
df.columns = header
print(df.shape)
return df['your_col_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing how you're creating `result.summary()` et al, but it's likely that the `SimpleTable` API follows similar/related pandas APIs, in which case you're looking for the `columns` attribute (note the plural 's').